# Vue.js - "Bind" bootstrap modal to Vue model

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

So, in my Vue instance, I have a `currentTask` model, which is null by default.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '...',

    data: {
        currentTask: null
    }
});
```

When I click on a 'task-item', which has `v-on="click: openTask"` directive, i want to launch the modal with the currentTask:

```js
methods: {
    openTask: function(e) {
        this.currentTask = this.clickedTask;
        $('#task-modal').modal('show');

        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

This is working just fine, although I don't know if there is a more "magical" way to two-way bind the whole modal + visibility to the currentTask.

Now, what I need, if there is no better way to go about this, is to somehow listen for the modal close event, which normally we would do in jQuery with `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {});` inside of Vue and set `this.currentTask = null;`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use a [custom directive](http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html) to handle this.

```
Vue.directive('task-selector', {
   bind: function () {
      var vm = this.vm;
      var el = $(this.el);
      el.on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
         vm.data.currentTask = 'whatever value you want here';
      });
   },
   update: function (newValue, oldValue) {
      // i don't think you have anything here  
   },
   unbind: function () {
      // not sure that you have anything here
      // maybe unbind the modal if bootstrap has that
   }
})
```

In your html you would need to put this directive on the modal element like so...

```
<div id="task-modal" v-task-selector>
   ... modal body stuff here...
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working, I will try to understand why and will post back.

Comment: I haven't found why it's not working. I have a `console.log('hello');` in the bind, update and unbind callbacks and none triggers, so I guess the directive is not even being bound. I did `<div id="task-modal" v-task-modal class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">` in the element and `Vue.directive('task-modal', {...`.